# How to transform str to bytes (not change every byte) in python?

Tags: python, binary

for example,how to change s to b here?

```
s="\x00\x01\x02\x00\xad\xaa"
b=b"\x00\x01\x02\x00\xad\xaa"
```

I know str.encode() will return a encoded bytes, but it did not meet my expectations(because sometimes len(str)!=len(bytes)).

I read some method change str to bytes such as encode/decode, base64, but all it can't meet my expectations

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's built in `encode` method with `raw_unicode_escape` encoding to preserve literal escape sequences.

```py
s = '\x00\x01\x02\x00\xad\xaa'
b = s.encode(encoding='raw_unicode_escape')
print(b)
>>> b'\x00\x01\x02\x00\xad\xaa'
```